# Returning a Generic Empty List

Tags: java, generics

How do I return a custom object which uses generic as an empty list?

I have extended the List interface and created my own custom type

```
public interface MyCustomList<T>
  extends List<T>
{
```

In a class, I have a method which returns a custom list but I always end up with a compiler error.  Basically the default implementation of this method should return an empty list but I cant get it to work since I am encountering below error.
'incompatible types'

```
public MyCustomList<MyCustomBean> getCodes(String code)
{
    return  Collections.<MyCustomList<MyCustomBean>>emptyList();
}
```

Whats the proper way of sending back a 'generified' empty list implementation?

Comment: Why do you need a custom List interface?

Comment: Not an answer, but an explanation: The reason you can't do this is because the signature for `Collections.emptyList()` is `<T> List<T> emptyList()`.  That means it's going to return a List of T.  When you call the `emptyList()` like that, it's actually returning `List<MyCustomList<MyCustomBean>>` but your `getCodes()` method says it'll return a `MyCustomList<MyCustomBean>` so you get a compile time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything wrong with a perfunctory impl?

```
class MyCustomListImpl<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements MyCustomList<T> {}

return new MyCustomListImpl<MyCustomBean>();
```

Comment: `MyCustomList` is just interface. In your decision you will have to implement all `List` interface in anonymous class in `return` statement.

Comment: @Andremoniy oops - didn't noticed that. Fixed. :)

Comment: Went with this answer but the other answers are cool to me also..thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.emptyList` returns a `List<T>`, whose implementation is [hidden](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.EmptyList). Since your `MyCustomList` interface is an *extension* of `List`, there's no way that method can be used here.

In order for this to work you will need to make an implementation of an empty `MyCustomList`, in the same way that the core API's `Collections` implements an empty `List` implementation, and then use it instead. For example:

```
public final class MyEmptyCustomList<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements MyCustomList<T> {

    private static final MyEmptyCustomList<?> INSTANCE = new MyEmptyCustomList<Object>();

    private MyEmptyCustomList() { }

    //implement in same manner as Collections.EmptyList

    public static <T> MyEmptyCustomList<T> create() {

        //the same instance can be used for any T since it will always be empty
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        MyEmptyCustomList<T> withNarrowedType = (MyEmptyCustomList<T>)INSTANCE;

        return withNarrowedType;
    }
}
```

Or more accurately, hide the class itself as an implementation detail:

```
public class MyCustomLists { //just a utility class with factory methods, etc.

    private static final MyEmptyCustomList<?> EMPTY = new MyEmptyCustomList<Object>();

    private MyCustomLists() { }

    private static final class MyEmptyCustomList<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements MyCustomList<T> {
        //implement in same manner as Collections.EmptyList
    }

    public static <T> MyCustomList<T> empty() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        MyCustomList<T> withNarrowedType = (MyCustomList<T>)EMPTY;
        return withNarrowedType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case this is impossible until you will have proper implementation of your interface `MyCustomList`.

**UPD:** `Collections.emptyList()` returns special implementation of `List` interface, which of course is not convertible to your `MyCustomList`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `Collections.emptyList()` for this purpose. This is type safe and seems to do what you are looking for!

Comment: No, I meant not to use the custom interface(MyCustomList) and just use the actual types in the method prototype. And where you want to return the empty List, simple use Collections.emptyList(). Is there a reason to define your own interface ?